# cinnamon crashes after installing nvidia driver

Tags: linux-mint, drivers, nvidia, cinnamon

I installed the new nvidia driver with opengl 4.5 capabilities after a fresh install of linux mint (the usual way: stopping mdm, disabling nouveau, installing, starting mdm, nvidia-xconfig). But now cinnamon crashes and I only have a resolution of 640x480. Also I get an error that it can't get the correct configuration of the monitors or something similar to that. How do I fix that?

Edit: the error message started with "could not apply stored configuration to monitors"

**Edit2:**
I have the following errors in /var/log/Xorg.0.log:

> > (EE) NVIDIA: Failed to initialize the NVIDIA kernel module. Please see the
> >     (EE) NVIDIA:     system's kernel log for additional error messages and
> >     (EE) NVIDIA:     consult the NVIDIA README for details.
> >     (EE) No devices detected.
> >     (EE) Failed to initialize GLX extension (Compatible NVIDIA X driver not   found)

**Edit3:**
lsmod shows

> > video                  19476  1 nouveau

so that's odd, I guess Nouveau loads before the nvidia drivers get a chance to do so?

**Edit4:**
Ok, I disabled nouveau bei blacklisting it and updating initramfs. Now it seems to work! Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the exact error message?

Comment: @drs: I edited my question.

Comment: Check `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` for errors.  The most interesting ones can be found with `grep EE /var/log/Xorg.0.log`.

Comment: @drs: I did so and edited my question.

Comment: Could you give some instructions for the fix?

Comment: @Oliver Shaw: Sorry, I can't remember :(